# Annotation on star types

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I have a very simple example

```kotlin
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE, AnnotationTarget.EXPRESSION)
annotation class Test

data class MyClass(
    val setInt: Set<@Test Int>,
    val setStar: Set<@Test *>,
)
```

Field `setInt` is accepted just fine by the compiler, but for the field `setStar` the compiler produces an error `Type expected`, although my annotation is extremely generic: it only applies in source and on any expression.

Is this impossible? Is there a way around it?

Update:
here is [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/L10VOlIbf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is simply not allowed by the [syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/syntax-and-grammar.html).

The syntax of a [simple user type](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/syntax-and-grammar.html#grammar-rule-simpleUserType) is:

```
simpleUserType:
    simpleIdentifier [{NL} typeArguments]
typeArguments:
    '<'
    {NL}
    typeProjection
    {{NL} ',' {NL} typeProjection}
    [{NL} ',']
    {NL}
    '>'
typeProjection:
    ([typeProjectionModifiers] type)
    | '*'
typeProjectionModifiers:
    typeProjectionModifier {typeProjectionModifier}
typeProjectionModifier:
    (varianceModifier {NL})
    | annotation
```

Specifically, the production rule for `typeProjection` (which is part of the `typeArguments`) includes two alternatives: either another type optionally prefixed with some modifiers (e.g. the annotations that you want to add), or the `*` character by itself.

The `*` is not a type or an expression. It is a [*projection*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-projections), just like how `in Int` or `out String` are projections, not types (though `Int` and `String` are types). You can't annotate a projection, but you can annotate the type that is used in a projection. It just so happens that `*` is a projection that doesn't use any types.

As a workaround (for `Set` at least), you can change the star projection to just `Any?`, which mean the same thing in the case of `Set`.

```
data class MyClass(
    val setInt: Set<@Test Int>,
    val setStar: Set<@Test Any?>,
)
```

Now you have a type to annotate!

Most of the time, you can rewrite a star projection to another projection that does use a type, see [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Unfortunately, in a real application, I have no control over what is going to be annotated with such an annotation. Good to know, that such behaviour is prohibited on the language level.

Answer (score 0):

I see you add an extra `,` in the end of `setStar`.

Try to delete that and will work fine.

Comment: Commas are allowed like this. You can verify this in the playground, I am updating my question.